# How to define a list with custom symbols?

Tags: lists, itemize, examples

I'd like to define a list like the following:

[image]

The nearest I found while googling was this:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[-] foo
\item[*] bar
\end{itemize}
```

But how can I now use a cross or a check symbol?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use e.g. the `\Checkmark` and `\XSolidBrush` symbols from the `bbding` package.
Good alternatives are `\ding{51}` and `\ding{55}` from the `pifont` package.

```
\usepackage{bbding}
%...
\begin{itemize}
  \item[\Checkmark] foo
  \item[\XSolidBrush] bar
\end{itemize}
```

You can even define a special macro for it:

```
\newcommand*\tick{\item[\Checkmark]}
\newcommand*\fail{\item[\XSolidBrush]}
% ...
\begin{itemize}
  \tick foo
  \fail  bar
\end{itemize}
```

See either [the comprehensive symbol list](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/) (search for "Checkmark") or [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) to find other symbols if you don't like the one above.

Comment: Thanks. Very good answer, all I need. However I want to add that your macro fails in my document: ! LaTeX Error: Command \check already defined.

Comment: Just call it differently, like `\tick` or any other name. The `\check` macro seems to be already defined.

Comment: On Debian-based systems you need to install `texlive-fonts-extra` to use `bbding`.

Answer (score 23):

Use a package which provides such symbols, such as MnSymbol, bbding or pifont. There are more. Use math mode within the square brackets if required.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
 \item[\ding{51}] yes
 \item[\ding{55}] no 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could define your own name for the symbol by `\newcommand`.

Answer (score 16):

Dingbats are easy to obtain, from symbol packages like `pifont` etc. Further more, `pifont` package provides a `dinglist` environment:

```
% in preamble \usepackage{pifont}
\begin{dinglist}{52}
  \item foo
  \item bar
\end{dinglist}
```

[image]

In standard classes, `itemize` environments use `\labelitemi`, `\labelitemii`, `\labelitemiii` and `\labelitemiv` for item labels. You can also redefine them and use standard `itemize`.

```
% preamble
\usepackage{pifont}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\ding{52}}
% document
\begin{itemize}
  \item foo
  \item bar
\end{itemize}
```