# Can one replace bullet points with graphics?

Tags: beamer, graphics, lists, itemize

Is it possible to replace bullet points in an itemize environment with graphics? I can find answers about replacing bullet points with other symbols, but in all the examples I can find, these symbols are given by LaTeX commands and are not separate graphics files.

I am interested in finding out if this is possible both in Beamer and other standard document classes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simply replace the mentioned LaTeX commands with `\includegraphics[<options>]{<image>}` (`graphicx` package). You can adjust the scale or height of the images using the `scale` and `height` option, receptively. Using either `ex` or `em` as unit for the height will scale the image depending on the font size.

For beamer you do it the following way (See also 
[Change bullet style / formatting in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11168/change-bullet-style-formatting-in-beamer/))

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{image}{\small\includegraphics[height=1.6ex]{myimage}}
\defbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{image}{\scriptsize\includegraphics[height=1.6ex]{myimage}}
\defbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{image}{\tiny\includegraphics[height=1.6ex]{myimage}}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[image]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[image]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[image]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Example}

\begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
    \begin{itemize}
        \item A
        \item B
        \item C
        \begin{itemize}
            \item A
            \item B
            \item C
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

For the normal `itemize` you can redefine `\labelitemi`, `\labelitemii`, `\labelitemiii` and `\labelitemiv` for the four possible nesting levels.

If you want to have *different* images for different items you should simply define macros which call `\item` with the optional argument as described by me in [How to define a list with custom symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10192/how-to-define-a-list-with-custom-symbols/10194#10194).

For images this would look e.g. like this:

```
\newcommand*\tick{\item[\includegraphics[height=1.6ex]{tickimg}]}
\newcommand*\fail{\item[\includegraphics[height=1.6ex]{failimg}]}
```

Comment: Very good comprehensive answer! I also like `\defbeamertemplate` which my solution didn't use.

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks, for that I like your `\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\upbullet}` because it is more direct, which is good for small changes which are are not reused often.

Comment: @MartinScharrer i adopted this solution myself by i later found out that it does not play well with `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` (the image remains fully showed when the text is grayed out). is there a way to fix this? or at least include a different image when the item is covered?

Comment: @capitalaslash: Sorry, no idea. My beamer template knowledge doesn't go so far.

Comment: Your newcommand definition don't work. It results in `! Argument of \beamer@includegraphics has an extra }`. It seems it cannot handle the double `[` of graphics arguments inside the item arguments.

Answer (score 21):

Here's a beamer way, using `setbeamertemplate` which Leo mentioned:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand*{\upbullet}{\includegraphics[width=1em]{up}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\upbullet}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
 \item One
 \item Two
 \item Three
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can i do this only for particular itemize section?

Answer (score 12):

Redefine `\labelitemi`. The origin definition is (in standard document classes):

```
\newcommand\labelitemi{\textbullet}
```

You can redefine it as your wish:

```
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\includegraphics{foo}}
```

---

For `beamer`, you can use `\setbeamertemplate`. Please refer manual of beamer for details. And you can see this question:

[Change bullet style / formatting in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11168/change-bullet-style-formatting-in-beamer/)

Comment: Or do the same thing using the `enumitem` package. `\setitemize[1]{\includegraphics{foo}}`, where `[1]` is the depth of the itemization.

Comment: @Alan Munn: Very good advice! `enumitem` is great for most documents. Just a remark, since also `beamer` is a part of the question: `enumitem` doesn't work with `beamer`.