# beamer: change individual bullet color in itemize list

Tags: beamer, lists, color, itemize

Is there a "nice" way to change the color of individual bullet points?
For example imagine a list like this:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item A
  \begin{itemize}
    \item pro 1
    \item con 1
    \item pro 2
  \end{itemize}
  \item B
  \begin{itemize}
    \item pro 3
    \item con 2
    \item con 3
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

How can I make pro bullets green and cons bullets red?

BTW.: I use the `circle` innertheme

Comment: Related questions: [How to define a list with custom symbols?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10192/2975), [Can one replace bullet points with graphics?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12735/2975) and [Change bullet style / formatting in Beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11168/2975).

Comment: While the above linked questions explain how to change the itemize styles in `beamer` globally or per-item for a normal document, I couldn't find one explaining how to change the used beamer style for single `\item`s yet. This makes this question IMHO a non-duplicate.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You don't need to put "Latex" (which should be written as LaTeX) into the title (or the tag list) on this site, because everything here is about (La)TeX anyway. You can also use back-ticks `\`` to mark inline code, package names and settings. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help for a full list.

Answer (score 30):

Here's a more `beamer` way to do things.

The idea is to make an "action" environment that changes the bullet colour.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\newenvironment{proenv}{\only{\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=green}}}{}
\newenvironment{conenv}{\only{\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=red}}}{}
\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Some pros and cons}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item<pro@1-> A pro item
      \item<con@1-> A con item
      \item A neutral  item
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The syntax of adding the action requires you to specify the slide range that the action will apply to; you should set this to `1-` (which means slide 1 and all further slides) otherwise the colour will change back to the default colour theme if you are uncovering any parts of the slide.

[image: output of code]

Comment: Why is it impossible to get colored items if you add `\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=blue}` in the beginning of the document? Is there a way to avoid it to override everything?

Comment: @s__C I'm not quite sure the reason, but as a fix you can replace `local structure` with `item` in my code and things will work as advertised.

Comment: Just one thing remaining : why is it also coloring all items that are one level below (encapsulated itemize)?

Comment: @s__C Because that semantically makes sense? :)  But I'm not sure how the inheritance structure works in Beamer, so I don't have a quick answer to that, nor much time to investigate.

Answer (score 10):

You can define new commands based on `\item` and use its optional argument to obtain colored bullets; I don't know if this is "nice", though:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand*\MyPitem{%
  \item[\color{green}\scalebox{0.9}{\textbullet}]}
\newcommand*\MyCitem{%
  \item[\color{red}\scalebox{0.9}{\textbullet}]}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item A
  \begin{itemize}
    \MyPitem pro 1
    \MyCitem con 1
    \MyPitem pro 2
  \end{itemize}
  \item B
  \begin{itemize}
    \MyPitem pro 3
    \MyCitem con 2
    \MyCitem con 3
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: True, but this is more a duplicate of [How to define a list with custom symbols?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10192/2975). See my comments under the question.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: yes, I didn't read the question you linked; should I delete my answer?

Comment: No, it not really necessary. Your example includes the textbullets which some people might want.

Comment: This answer is extremely useful in case you need to adjust symbol and color. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I was with the same problem. But I figured it out you could use the "\bullet" command and change its color:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item[\textcolor{green}{$\bullet$}] Pro:
  \item[\textcolor{red}{$\bullet$}] Con:
  \item[\textcolor{blue}{$\bullet$}] Neutral:
\end{itemize}
```

Result:

[image]

If you want to create a new command with this `\textcolor{blue}{$\bullet$}` it would be even better.