# Different colours for the bullets in itemize environment

Tags: lists, itemize, enumitem

In the following list, the colour of the bullet will be fixed:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Good point 1
\item Good point 2
\item Poor statement 1 
\item Poor Statement 2
\end{itemize}
```

Is there anyway to modify the above environment to have different colours for the bullets depending on the entry?  Something like

```
Green Bullet Good point 1
Green Bullet Good point 2
Red Bullet Poor statement 1
Red Bullet Poor statement 2
```

Comment: Doing this in a printed document seems a bad idea to me but it could be useful for a computer presentation. Can you say a bit more about the context, provide a MWE, ...?

Comment: One way to do this in beamer: [beamer: change individual bullet color for pros and cons list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14366/2693).

Comment: I am looking at the performance of a client at a given standard, which consists of sub standards. Obviously the performance may be satisfactory or poor for different sub standards. I would like to change the colour of the bullet depending on what the performance is.

Comment: Alan I am using report document class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with the `enumitem` package quite easily:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newif\ifgooditem
\gooditemtrue
\newcommand\gooditem{\gooditemtrue\item}
\newcommand\baditem{\gooditemfalse\item}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label={\ifgooditem\color{green}\else\color{red}\fi\textbullet}]
\gooditem A good item
\baditem A bad item
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

with latex beamer, you can use this MWE

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\gooditem}[1]{\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=green}\item #1} 
\newcommand{\pooritem}[1]{\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=red}\item #1} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \gooditem good
    \pooritem bad
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Micha.  As I mentioned earlier I am using report document class.