# Change item symbol within itemize in beamer

Tags: beamer, formatting, lists, itemize

I'm using `beamer` to create a presentation and I'd like to mix item shapes. Namely, I'd like to use something like

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[\circle] Something
\item[\triangle] A conclusion
\end{itemize}
```

What's the name of the triangle shape used as a beamer template?

Comment: please see http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: @touhami Identifying symbols *per se* is not really the issue.

Comment: @AlanMunn I understand the question in this way, now I am not sure :-)

Answer (score 9):

Adapting the answer here:

- [beamer: change individual bullet color in itemize list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14319/2693)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\newenvironment{trienv}{\only{\setbeamertemplate{items}[triangle]}}{}
\newenvironment{squareenv}{\only{\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]}}{}
\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Some bullet shapes}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item<tri@1-> A triangle item
      \item<square@1-> A square item
      \item A circle  item
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]