# Change enumerate items to color boxes in beamer

Tags: beamer, formatting, lists, enumerate

**Problem:**

I am trying to find a way to customise enumerate items. Basically I want to keep the standard version but also want to change certain items to color boxes.

**Minimal Working Example:**

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{%
  \usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
  \raisebox{1.5pt}{\colorbox{bg}{\color{fg}\footnotesize\insertenumlabel}}%
}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Enum
  \item Enum
  \item Enum
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

[image]

Basically I want to be able to change the color of a specific enumerate box. The text that follows the item should always be vertically centered.

**Update 1:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\newcommand{\specialitem}[3][white]{%
  \item[%
    \colorbox{#2}{\textcolor{#1}{\makebox(14,14){#3}}}%
  ]
}

\definecolor{editorOrange}{cmyk}{0, 0.8, 1, 0}
\definecolor{editorBlue}{cmyk}{1, 0.6, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorGreen}{cmyk}{0.66, 0, 0.87, 0}
\definecolor{editorPink}{cmyk}{0, 1, 0, 0}

\begin{document}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=9mm}

\begin{enumerate}
  \specialitem{editorPink}{H} \textcolor{editorPink}{Hyper} lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut auctor metus ac fermentum rutrum. Phasellus convallis scelerisque nulla, eu sollicitudin diam rutrum id. Curabitur dapibus dapibus nisl ac tempus. Praesent viverra tortor a mollis efficitur. Donec vehicula risus nec varius ornare. Suspendisse facilisis ante eu ex ultricies viverra.

  \specialitem{editorBlue}{T} \textcolor{editorBlue}{Text} lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

  \specialitem{editorOrange}{M} \textcolor{editorOrange}{Markup} lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

  \specialitem{editorGreen}{L} \textcolor{editorGreen}{Language} lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

**Update 1 (output):**

[image]

Comment: Related: [beamer: change individual bullet color in itemize list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14366)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the items manually inside an `itemize`. Below I defined `\specialitem[<text colour>]{<colour>}{<content>}` to act like `\item`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{%
  \usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
  \raisebox{1.5pt}{\colorbox{bg}{\color{fg}\footnotesize\insertenumlabel}}%
}
\newcommand{\specialitem}[3][white]{%
  \item[%
    \colorbox{#2}{\textcolor{#1}{\makebox[1em]{#3}}}%
  ]
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Enum
  \item Enum
  \item Enum
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
  \specialitem{red!80}{H} \textcolor{red!80}{Here} is an item

  \specialitem{blue!60!white}{T} \textcolor{blue!60!white}{This} is another item

  \specialitem{orange!80!white}{M} \textcolor{orange!80!white}{Maybe} another item

  \specialitem{green!70!white}{L} \textcolor{green!70!white}{Let} me show you another item
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: Proposal: If the width of the boxes would equal `\newlength{\Xheight}
\settoheight{\Xheight}{X}` they would seem more symmetric?

Comment: @samcarter: The current width is consistent at `1em`. One could add a `\strut` as part of the definition to ensure the same height, or a `\vphantom{X}`. No need to define a new length.

Comment: @Werner I have added an update and for some reason my version does not center the boxes in line with the text. The boxes are elevated. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @kexxcream: You're using `\makebox(x,y)`. Use `\makebox[1em]`.

Comment: @Werner The box only increase horizontally when using 1, 2, or 3 em. How can I increase both horizontal/vertical while keeping it center to the text?

Comment: @kexxcream: Add `\strut`... `\makebox[1em]{\strut#3}`.

Comment: @Werner Works like a charm! Thank you kindly for your time, it's greatly appreciated.