# How to make a right-facing fleur-de-lis list item bullet

Tags: lists, itemize

Does anyone know how to make a right-facing, correctly-sized (12pt), nice-looking (crisp, maybe SVG or something), fleur-de-lis as a list item bullet?

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12735/), but it's not quite what I'm after because I'm having trouble finding a correctly-sized, right-facing fleur-de-lis image and I don't have the skills to draw one myself. When I try to scale one that I find using GIMP then it gets ugly very quickly.

I found some fonts, but they all face up instead of to the right, and I'm not sure how I could use a system font as a list item even with XeLaTeX.

There is a unicode fleur-de-lis, but my system (OS 10.6) doesn't seem to render it correctly (difficult to explain), and anyway, it faces up; not to the right.

The fleur de lis below faces upward. I'd like it rotated 90 degrees clockwise so it looks a bit like an arrow facing right.

[image: Fleur de lis]

Comment: Can you please provide an image of (or a link to) a right-facing fleur-de-lis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option using the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to define an itemize-like list using the rotated fleur-de-lis from the image provided as the question as the label; find the image you want in the desired format and used it in the `\RLis` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\RLis{%
  \raisebox{-.25ex}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\includegraphics[height=10pt]{lis}}}}
\newlist{litemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[litemize,1]{label=\RLis}

\begin{document}

\begin{litemize}
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{litemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! This works very nicely. I don't understand how the scaling is handled so nicely (in comparison with scaling in the GIMP) given the fact that the image is a jpg rather than a SVG and many times larger than 10pt, but it looks very nice. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

I did a [Google search for SVG images named `fleur-de-lis`](https://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&authuser=0&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&biw=1366&bih=677&bvm=pv.xjs.s.en_US.yR6OC0MmjVk.O&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=6b0WUpvRIaKoiQKgtYHwDg&q=fleur-de-lis&tbs=ift:svg#authuser=0&fp=42b710ae39293482&hl=en&q=fleur-de-lis&tbm=isch&tbs=ift:svg,itp:clipart&um=1&imgdii=_) and found quite the selection:

[image]

Then, using [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/), converted the SVG image to PDF (or EPS), and with the help of [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) together with [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) to insert it, rotated and resized in the appropriate place:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{enumitem,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label=\resizebox{!}{.7em}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\includegraphics{fleur-de-lis}}}]
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Last item
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

A close-up:

[image]

Comment: Very nice. Inkscape is new to me. I'll hafta check it out. Thank you.

Comment: you may want to lower the fleur-de-lis a bit, so that the point is centered between the baseline and the cap height.  or lining it up with the middle stroke of the "F" would look nice too.  (at this size, when the right-hand edge sits on the baseline, it will always add extra space above the line in which it's used.  here, that may be a bit too much of a good thing.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I've incorporated your comments. Thanks; leaned too much towards the request than what looks good.