# How to create Bullet-List with Fancy Bullet Shapes?

Tags: formatting, lists, enumerate, itemize

Can somebody please provide some hint on how to achieve the following 2 types of bullet-lists?

Type-1: [Diamond Shaped Bullets]

[image]

Type-2: [Round Shaped Bullets]

[image]

Comment: You can use `\item[$\blacklozenge$]`. But this is a manual procedure. You can redefine the `enumitemi` to do this automatic.

Comment: Have a look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10192/14100

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package; a little example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=0.3pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[label=\EightFlowerPetalRemoved]
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{itemize}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\circled{\Alph{enumi}}]
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can do it without `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\labelitemi{\EightFlowerPetalRemoved}
\begin{itemize}
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{itemize}

\renewcommand\labelenumi{\circled{\Alph{enumi}}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

And without `enumitem` and `TikZ`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\labelitemi{\ding{117}}
\begin{itemize}
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{itemize}

\renewcommand\labelenumi{\textcircled{\raisebox{-0.02ex}{\scriptsize\kern-0.2pt\Alph{enumi}}}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have a small problem. In case of circled bullets: "\renewcommand\labelenumi{\textcircled{\Alph{enumi}}}
" The alphabets: 'A', 'B' ..etc seem to be overflowing out of the Circle. Can we increase the size of the circle wrapping the alphabets here?

Comment: @SandeepSingh try now (I added `\footnotisize` to reduce the font size.)

Comment: @SandeepSingh I made additional modifications to correct the size and position of the characters inside the circle.