# How to format the following

Tags: formatting

I am trying to write the following in latex (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxTJoMOw_GADdGJLQU1aRHNDVEk/view?resourcekey=0-UTvJmWGuAWgWY4sJ2pNhFA) and am having trouble with formatting the top line across, the name on the left, and the text on the right above it. I also am unsure on how to format the citations at the bottom compared to the usual formatting I use.

Thanks, any hints/help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can do  that with the `fancyhdr` package, or  with  `titleps` , which comes with `titlesec`.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks! Also, how do I type in Cambria math font?

Comment: In this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108624/how-to-use-checkmark-and-cambria-math, there's a way to do it. However it requires using `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

Comment: Ok, and sorry for asking so many questions, but I think for my personal statement, this kind of title/name will be better. How did this person format their title/name and sections in such a way? (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxTJoMOw_GADUUFQOHZZWVJjbDg/view?resourcekey=0-US5fI8mpNRYkMT05daZgAw)

Comment: You can define, with fancyhdr, what is in the left part and the right part of the header. Take a look at the package documentation for details.