# Tree like items list

Tags: lists, tufte

I'm trying to build a list in a file based on the Tufte-Latex book template: https://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/

In keeping with the clean design, I don't need any font changes, blod or italics, and would prefer to avoid bullet points. Any idea how I can recreate the neat line-marking of this example?

[image: Picture of layout]

Comment: Hm, the migration ate a comment. Here it is: “This question rather belongs on [Tex.SE]. Similar questions have been asked there before, like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10192/how-to-define-a-list-with-custom-symbols. It seems like the package `bbding`, among others, can do what you're looking for. –  creimers 3 hours ago”

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Thanks for the migration! I didn't realize there was a dedicated spot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick hack with Tikz, I'm sure this can be improved/made more general with some work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newcommand{\mylist}{\tikz[overlay]\draw(-.2,-.2)--(-.2,.5) [path fading=east](-.2,.15)--(.1,.15);}
\newcommand{\myitem}{\item[\mylist]}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
   \item Google
   \begin{itemize}
      \myitem Picasa
      \myitem Feedburner
      \myitem Youtube
   \end{itemize}
   \item Microsoft
   \begin{itemize}
      \myitem Corel Corporation
      \myitem Zignlas
      \myitem MyBlogLog
   \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thankyou!

(and now I can draw all kinds of shapes :) )

Comment: @user3601030 you're welcome. I changed the question title to better reflect its content and to help those who'll search for something similar. Feel free to improve it. If one of the answers does solve your problem consider accepting it.

Answer (score 4):

My answer builds off of dcmst's answer.  I've reused his `tikz` code.

If you want to redefine all second-level `enumerate` environments to use this symbol, you can add `\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\mylist}` to the preamble of your document.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

% From dcmst's answer at <http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175204/80>.
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newcommand{\mylist}{\tikz[overlay]\draw(-.2,-.2)--(-.2,.5) [path fading=east](-.2,.15)--(.1,.15);}

% All second-level enumerated lists should use the \mylist bullet.
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\mylist}

% This generates fake lists for us.
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

It works okay if you only use a second-level list.

\blindlistlist[2]{enumerate}[3]

If you use a third-level list, you'll have to do something a bit fancier.

\blindlistlist[3]{enumerate}[3]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

And I think I developed godbyk's answer when I had trouble with linespacing causes breaks in the line. I also added a second 'my object' for closing the list off at the bottom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%for fancy lists
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newcommand{\mylist}{\tikz[overlay]\draw(-.2,-.2)--(-.2,.4) [path fading=east](-.2,.15)--(.1,.15);} %adds the |- shape to the start of each list item
\newcommand{\mylistend}{\tikz[overlay]\draw(-.2,.15)--(-.2,.4) [path fading=east](-.2,.15)--(.1,.15);} %adds the |- shape to the start of each list item
\newcommand{\myitem}{\item[\mylist]} %defines the scope of the mylist command to be 2nd level sublists
\newcommand{\myitemend}{\item[\mylistend]} %defines the scope of the mylist command to be 2nd level sublists

% with an example in use:

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Google
        \begin{itemize}
        \myitem Youtube
        \myitem Google+
        \myitem Skybox
        \myitemend Googlemaps
        \end{itemize}
    \item Microsoft
        \begin{itemize}
        \myitem Corel Corporation
        \myitem Zignals
        \myitem ByteTaxi
        \myitemend Azure
        \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And thanks to @Heiko Oberdiek for his edit. Knowing enumerate counts as itemize for the purpose of using items has wiped out the about 400 "! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item." that i've been carefully ignoring :)