# How to do this type of slide in beamer? I want it in \usetheme{Warsaw}

Tags: beamer, two-column

This is a snapshot of a Microsoft PowerPoint presentation slide:

[image: this is snapshot of Microsoft PowerPoint presentation slide]

I have tried this code, but the text goes outside the slide and I want to use only Warsaw theme:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Mean monthly change in projected TMax under A2 and A1B scenarios of CGCM3 model}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.47\columnwidth}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1.8in]{CGCM3A2max}
\caption{CGCM3A2max}
\end{figure}

\begin{itemize}
\justifying
\item \scriptsize{The highest increase in Tmax is anticipated in the month of November under A1B scenarios in 2080s ie 2.31 $\circ$C. }
\item \scriptsize{On the contrary, highest decrease can be seen in the month of September (2.09$\circ$C) under A2 scenario in 2080s.}
\end{itemize}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.48\columnwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\justifying
\item \scriptsize{Significant decrease of 0.13-0.93, 0.11-1.42, 0.81-2.09 oC predicted for August and September}
\item \scriptsize{Significant increase in Tmax is predicted in winter season in the range of 0.09-1.82, 0.32-1.92, 0.52-2.31 oC respectively for three time periods under A2 and A1B scenario}
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1.8in]{CGCM3A1Bmax}
\caption{CGCM3A}
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Also tried another code but there is no space on right side as on left side of frame:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Mean monthly change in projected TMax under A2 and A1B scenarios of CGCM3 model}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.47\columnwidth}
\framebox{\includegraphics[width=1.95in]{CGCM3A2max}}
\begin{itemize}
\justifying
\item \scriptsize{The highest increase in Tmax is anticipated in the month of November under A1B scenarios in 2080s ie 2.31 $\circ$C. }
\item \scriptsize{On the contrary, highest decrease can be seen in the month of September (2.09$\circ$C) under A2 scenario in 2080s.}
\end{itemize}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.48\columnwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\justifying
\item \scriptsize{Significant decrease of 0.13-0.93, 0.11-1.42, 0.81-2.09 oC predicted for August and September}
\item \scriptsize{Significant increase in Tmax is predicted in winter season in the range of 0.09-1.82, 0.32-1.92, 0.52-2.31 oC respectively for three time periods under A2 and A1B scenario}
\end{itemize}
\framebox{\includegraphics[width=1.95in]{CGCM3A1Bmax}}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: There are nothing special in this format, apart form basic techniques as [include an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134187/how-to-add-a-jpg-image-in-latex), make [two columns in Beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228271/creating-two-columns-in-beamer) or add  a [custom item symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10192/how-to-define-a-list-with-custom-symbol). What is the problem?

Comment: @Stefan Pinnow I used aboce code but then i want some space on right side also as on left side of slide also it goes outside of the frame plz give some solution. I added my code which i have tried. thanks for ur time

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

[image]

What I've done?

smaller images without caption and just included with `\includegraphics`, not `figure` environment.

replaced unknown (at least for me) `\justifing` command with `\centering`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Mean monthly change in projected TMax under A2 and A1B scenarios of CGCM3 model}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{0.48\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image}
\smallskip
\begin{itemize}
\item \scriptsize{The highest increase in Tmax is anticipated in the month of November under A1B scenarios in 2080s ie 2.31 $\circ$C. }
\item \scriptsize{On the contrary, highest decrease can be seen in the month of September (2.09$\circ$C) under A2 scenario in 2080s.}
\end{itemize}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.48\columnwidth}
\centering
\begin{itemize}
\item \scriptsize{Significant decrease of 0.13-0.93, 0.11-1.42, 0.81-2.09 oC predicted for August and September}
\item \scriptsize{Significant increase in Tmax is predicted in winter season in the range of 0.09-1.82, 0.32-1.92, 0.52-2.31 oC respectively for three time periods under A2 and A1B scenario}
\end{itemize}
\smallskip
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```