# items with own icons/symbol, loaded from a png-file

Tags: itemize, wrapfigure

I would like to have a symbol (own drawn and saved as SymbolforLinkStartRecording.png) at the left and the text at the right. wrapfigure is working well, but I do not know how to define the end of using space right of the icon. *What command do I use to tell Latex: "now set the text **under** the figure?"*

\begin{center} and \end{center} does not work.

```
\section*{Start the Recording}
\begin{center}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.1\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=6ex]{images/SymbolforLinkStartRecording.png}
\end{wrapfigure}
Start the Recording with this link on the desktop
\end{center}
```

And I am looking for somathing like \begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize} **but** with own symbol for each item

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[picture1.png] first sentence
\item[picture2.png] second sentence
\end{itemize}
```

Or say it in other words: At the left a small picture as symbol. And at the right the explanatio of the symbol in words with text by using all known LaTex commands for text.

[image]

[image]

Comment: it is hard to understand your question, it would be easier to understand if you made a complete small document that showed the issue, and you said what change to the output you want (you can use `example-image` as the image name as that is in the distributions for testing). wrapfig does not work in lists (including `center` als what is th eintent of `\caption[start recording]{}` it will say Figure: 2 in the text and `Start recording`  in the list of figures?

Comment: I deleted \caption[start recording]{}. it is not important for the question

Comment: "wrapfig does not work in lists (including Center)". Then I am looking for something like wrapfig which is working in lists.

Comment: why do you need wrapfig at all??, from your description (especially after the edit) just use `itemize`

Comment: How can I use own pictures as Icons/symbols in a list of items? Sometimes with high 12pt, sometimes 120pt? And use the space at the right with all LaTeX commands?

Comment: Something like this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10192/how-to-define-a-list-with-custom-symbols but with symbols from an *.png-file

Comment: you can use `\includegraphics` anywhere that you can use text so you can do exactly that just replace the checkmarks by the images you want, as in my answer below.

Comment: Please take the first listing of the question, remove the begin and end center and thell me "What command do I use to tell Latex: "now set the text under the figure?"" Because as long as there is space on the right of the Picture Latex will use this space.

Comment: @u just use `\begin{wrapfig}[1]{l}` and it will only cut out 1 line (or `[2]` or however many lines you want.)  (but I doubt that wrapfig is the correct tool here you want an itemized list not a figure)

Comment: @user145365: Can you mock up an image of what you current have as output and what you're ultimately after using Word?

Answer (score 3):

Just use the form that you suggest, but of course including the image not just printing the name so

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[\includegraphics{picture1.png}] first sentence
\item[\includegraphics{picture2.png}] second sentence
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Ok, and how can I reach that - if the sentence is Long - the second line of text is moved in the way, that the first letter of the second line of text is in one vertical line with the first letter of the first line of text?

Comment: @user145365 I'm not sure I understood but see the `enumitem` package that gives lots of possibilities for list layouts