# Itemize with custom logo

Tags: itemize

I'm trying to use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395517/items-with-own-icons-symbol-loaded-from-a-png-file) to insert a custom png to itemize with.

I have a problem however, since the image moves out of the slide and is blurred.

I have tried

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[\includegraphics[width=0.3]{hardhat.png}] first sentence
\end{itemize}
```

to no avail.

Comment: Please provide a complete but minimal code example that can be compiled without further modification. Considering that it is your **12th** question.

Comment: Try width = 5mm

Comment: Fixed it, missing bracket. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228 before you ask the next question. This makes it easier and more likely that you get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here. First, you forgot the unit of your width. Second, You are nesting optional arguments. When reading an optional argument starting with `[`, TeX looks for the next `]` and considers everything in between the optional argument. In your case, the next `]` really belongs to the optional argument of `\includegraphics`, not `\item`. You can hide the inner argument with a group.

I would recommend using `enumitem` to change the label for the whole list at once.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item[{\includegraphics[width=1em]{example-image}}] first sentence
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[label={\includegraphics[width=1em]{example-image}}]
    \item first sentence
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @rodger_kicks You are welcome. Please consider the remarks in the comments to your question. Make your code snippet an MWE (yes, even though I already answered) and make a habit of including an MWE and any relevant error messages in future questions. You will find that the problem often reveals itself when you work on writing a complete and concise question. At the very least, it helps everyone else to help you as well as later visitors who have similar problems.

Comment: Good answer and comment. +1